# Make a nextjs application which uses API routes and sqlite into an offline desktop application. Is it possible, how can I do it?

Tags: sqlite, desktop-application, next.js13

I tried using tauri but it only works for the frontend files, although it does load properly in development mode when output is default or standalone

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'standalone',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I want to make an offline desktop application

Answer (score 0):

When you use `output: 'standalone'` the `nextjs` builder will generate a `out` file wich you can serve as static html for frontend context. But if you want to use the frontend with the backend you will need run the nextjs server, and to do this just remove the `output: 'standalone'` from the config options, and now you have two possibilities, using `npm run dev` or `npm run build` then `npm run start`, the difference is the `npm run dev` will run with all the dev tools and options, or run `npm run  build` that will create a file with only the files you need to run your application, then you use `npm run start` to start your server. To your purpose its cool use docker file to create an enviroment to your nextjs application and other to your sqlite database and leave then running localy, but just running it in your computer will work too.

Comment: Thankyou!!  Please tell me how can I make an executable

Comment: I have this links that maybe will help you to your purpose: [developing a desktop with next, rust and tauri](https://dev.to/valorsoftware/developing-a-desktop-application-via-rust-and-nextjs-the-tauri-way-2iin), [building an app with next and electron](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-app-next-js-electron/). The way of just starting the server like i say will create a localhost (offline) webhost on desktop (that you see on browsers) but if you want desktop app you will need tauri or other tools you prefer that you can see on the articles i send above. I hope this can help you.